# В "течение" или "течении"?

Tags: орфография

Есть крылатая фраза "Только идиот не меняет свою точку зрения в течени(е) жизни". Так вот, "в течениЕ" или "в течениИ"?

Comment: В течениИ, как и на протяжениИ, в течениЕ можно что-то вбивать, но правильно в этом случае- в течениИ

Comment: В течении реки, НО в течение какого-то времени.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**В** течени**Е** жизни. В данном случае это производный предлог, как и **в** продолжени**Е** (Значение времени) Но:  в течении реки произошли изменения(сущ. *течение* с предлогом *в* ), в продолжении повести мы встретимся с новыми героями  (сущ. *продолжение* с предлогом *в* )